# What is the "best" way to get and set a single cookie value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to increment a cookie value every time a page is referenced even if the page is loaded from cache. What is the "best" or most concise way to implement this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Stolen from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toUTCString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

using it:

```
var oldCount = parseInt(readCookie('hitCount'), 10) || 0;
createCookie('hitCount', oldCount + 1, 7);
```

as pointed out in the comments, you should cast to an int since cookies are stored and returned as strings. Using `foo++` or `++foo` will actually cast for you, but it's safer to know exactly what you're working with:

```
var x = "5";  // x = "5" (string)
x += 1;       // x = "51" (string!)
x += 5;       // x = "515" (string!)
++x;          // x = 516 (number)
```

Comment: readCookie returns a substring, you should cast it as a number when incrementing 1, otherwise you will have, 1, 11, 111, 1111...

Comment: You are missing escape and unescape for the value

Comment: Note that toGMTString has been now deprecated in favor of toUTCString

Answer (score 7):

Most of the old cookie handling functions I've seen use simple string manipulations for storing an retrieving values, like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) example, you can use other libraries, like [cookie-js](http://code.google.com/p/cookie-js/), a small *(< 100 lines)* utility for cookie access.

I personally use jQuery on my projects, and I use the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/), it's really simple to use:

```
var cookieName = "increment";

if ($.cookie(cookieName) == null){
  $.cookie(cookieName, 1, { expires: 10 });
}else{
  var newValue = Number($.cookie(cookieName)) + 1;
  $.cookie(cookieName, newValue, { expires: 10 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way is always the simplest:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  return (name = (document.cookie + ';').match(new RegExp(name + '=.*;'))) && name[0].split(/=|;/)[1];
}

// the default lifetime is 365 days
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var e = new Date;
  e.setDate(e.getDate() + (days || 365));
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ';expires=' + e.toUTCString() + ';path=/;domain=.' + document.domain;
}
```

these functions expect the value to be a simple string, but you can always JSON.stringify it if you want or maybe do something else with it...

Comment: kudos for a 1-liner in getCookie +1