# How to set multiple values with two differents expires dates

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set cookie in javascript with two values.
Each of theses have a different expiration date.

For example :

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate( now.getDate() + 2 );
document.cookie = "bar=foo;";
document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"

now = new Date();
now.setDate( now.getDate() + 30 );
document.cookie = "foo=bar;";
document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"
```

Is it correct?
How to set another value with an expiration date for 30 days for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that approach is correct.

Based on: [How can I set a cookie to expire after x days with this code I have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561687/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-to-expire-after-x-days-with-this-code-i-have) :

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Note, that **setTime()** and  **getTime()** work on milliseconds.
And a few words from me: as javascript's Date sucks, I recommend using moment.js library when working with dates, it's brilliant.

Comment: Ok, i'll look for moment.js. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found my reply here with the function "setCookie". I've specify differents values and it's working.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp