# little help understanding this set cookie function?

Tags: javascript, cookies, arguments

Rank newbie question (forgive me)--if there's a better forum for this,  let me know.  I want to set a cookie that expires after thirty days.  I've found a response here on stackoverflow and looked at several online explanations on how to set a cookie, but I'm having trouble fully understanding what I'm seeing.  Here's [the answer given on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561687/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-to-expire-after-x-days-with-this-code-i-have):

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var date, expires;
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Here's where you get to correct me when I'm wrong (please):

Line 1 creates a function called createCookie with three arguments, `name`, `value`, and `days`.  Those arguments are defined or set when the function is invoked with something like `createCookie(testCookie, ?, 30);`.  I have a question mark in for the argument `value` because I'm not sure what goes there.

Line 2 establishes two variables, `date` and `expires`, without assigning anything to those variables.

Line 3 says if the argument `days` and then goes right into executing some lines.  This is outside my JS understanding, as so far  I've done things like `if (x > 10) {` where `x > 10` defines a condition that when true, the code in the following brackets gets executed, and if not, it skips to the else part of the if/else. `days` isn't a condition as I understand it.  I suppose my understanding this part isn't paramount, as long as it works.

Line 4 creates a variable called date and assigns the current date to it.

Line 5 `date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));` does math using the function's argument `days` to come up with the actual expiration date and assign it to the variable `date`.

Line 6 `expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();` assigns a value to the variable `expires`, but I don't quite follow, as it appears that value is a concatenation of `expires` which is undefined at that point, plus the value of the argument `date` expressed as a string?  Also, it looks like `toGMTString()` is deprecated now?  Again, it's probably the case that my understanding of this isn't of utmost importance; my lack thereof, though, adds to my overall confusion.

Line 8 sets the cookie with `name` plus the string `"="` plus `value` plus `expires` plus the string `"; path=/"`.  I still don't know what `value` should be...

Anyone want to help me understand this, please?  Thanks!

Comment: The value is "What you want to store in the cookie" and you need to learn about truthy values.

Comment: For `Line 3`, everything in JavaScript can be used as a condition because every value has either a "truthy" or "falsey" evaluation. The "falsey" values are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys--appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 1 - value is the data you want to store in the cookie.

`createCookie("testCookie", "The value I want to store", 30);`

Line 3 - That is a truthy check, it is checking to make sure days is not undefined.

Line 6 - I think you are confusing the string "expires" for the variable expires. And for the GMT, probably written before it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) { // this passes in the values for the cookie you want to store
    var date, expires; // set the variables
    if (days) { // check to make sure days is not undefined
        date = new Date(); // sets todays date
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000)); // does maths to make it expiry after `day` parameter you passed into the function.
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); // sets the expiry date
    } else {
        expires = ""; // else if days is undefined sets nothing to expiry
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; // sets the cookie.
}
```