# Referencing cookies set in VB.NET with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

In the beginning, I set a cookie value like this:

```
Response.Cookies("UserInfo")("UserName") = "Bob"
```

And it was good.

In the end, I need to read that cookie in javascript. But I have no idea how to do that. The documentation for javascript and cookies (especially those set like I have above) is poor at best. Most cookie-reading functions out there seem to only accept 1 argument (cookie name). But as we clearly see here, I have to pass two arguments to get the value for "Bob".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert(document.cookie);` will show you everything available to JavaScript.

Inserting Bob from the VB side gives something like `UserInfo=Username=Bob`.

Let's add something else, like Bob's favorite color:

```
Response.Cookies("UserInfo")("FavoriteColor") = "Chartreuse"
```

Now the cookie is `UserInfo=Username=Bob&FavoriteColor=Chartreuse`

One way to get at the cookie values is to take the whole collection and split it on the semi-colon:

```
var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(";")
```

In your case, you'll also need to split UserInfo cookie using the ampersand, and then you'll have access to each of your UserInfo key/value pairs.

There are plenty of examples here on StackOverflow about handling cookies in Javascript; [here's one that I've found useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript/260880#260880)