# how to use javascript for cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “best” way to get and set a single cookie value using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript)

I am trying to figure out how to use cookies with JavaScript. I am trying to store an email address, address, and phone number. Can anyone help? I have tried looking around the google machine for help, but I am not finding anything useful.

Comment: Please read: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: The w3schools didn't help me, I've already looked there.

Comment: [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) has a good resource on this, but as I see the duplicate question has the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the first question I've ever posted on here. Why do people think this is a duplicate?

Answer (score -1):

Heard of google? :) 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

But if you are using HTML5 it is even easier. 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: w3schools was one of the first places I looked. I don't think it explains cookies very well.

Comment: -1 w3schools is a terrible resource and webstorage has nothing to do with cookies.