# How Can I Set a Cookie on Click?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “best” way to get and set a single cookie value using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript)

I made a notification bar which you can see at the top of the site.  There is a p tag with the text "close x" in it which when clicked will add a class to the container using jquery and hide the bar.  What I am trying to do though is create a cookie for the user when they click this so that the choice to hide the bar is saved until they end their session on the site.

I really don't know much about setting up cookies, any ideas?

Here is the live version to see: http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Google "JavaScript cookie", first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery -Cookie plugin

**SET COOKIE**

```
$.cookie('SampleKey', 'SampleValue', { path: '/' });
```

**GET COOKIE**

```
$.cookie('SampleKey');
```

I assume you have a div where you want to write the text 'Closed'
**UPDATE**

HTML

```
<div id="close"></div>
```

JS

```
if($.cookie('CookieKey')=='closed'){
    $("#close").html('Closed');
}
```

Comment: How would I write the jquery to say the php equivalent of "if($cookievalue == 'closed'){echo 'class="closed"'}

Comment: What is the name of your cookie key?