# Cookie to hold multiple values including a variable?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to save multiple variables in a cookie and have and this is the code:

```
function changeColors(){
//get the numbers from the html
var rd = parseInt(document.getElementById("red").value);
var gr = parseInt(document.getElementById("green").value);
var bl = parseInt(document.getElementById("blue").value);
var op = parseFloat(document.getElementById("opacity").value);


//convert the decimal into hexadecimal

var rdhex = (rd < 16) ? "0" + rd.toString(16) : rd.toString(16);
var grhex = (gr < 16) ? "0" + gr.toString(16) : gr.toString(16);
var blhex = (bl < 16) ? "0" + bl.toString(16) : bl.toString(16);

//concatenate all hex to generate a color
var hexcode = "#" + rdhex + grhex + blhex;

//view the change in the browser
document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML = hexcode;
//change opacity
document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = op;
}

function WriteCookie()
{
if( document.myform.name.value == "" ){
    alert("Enter some value!");
    return;
}

cookievalue= escape(document.myform.red.value) + ";" +
    escape(document.myform.red.value)+ ";"+
    escape(document.myform.green.value)+ ";"+
    escape(document.myform.blue.value)+ ";"+
    escape(document.myform.opacity.value)+ ";";
document.cookie="color=" + cookievalue;
alert("Setting Cookies : " + "color=" + cookievalue );

// To revise!!!How do we set multiple values to one cookie?
function ReadCookie()
{
var allcookies = document.cookie;
alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

// Get all the cookies pairs in an array
cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');
```

I need to store the Name, RGB and opacity in a cookie so that later on the user can choose from previous colors that he has managed himself. My question is how can I store the var hexcode and opacity together with the name of the color in a cookie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can join the values together with `join()`, i.e.:

```
var separator = ":" // or whatever
var values = [name, rgb, opacity].join(separator);

// then you store the values in a cookie
document.cookie = "myValues=" + values;
```

For storing values in cookies see [What is the "best" way to get and set a single cookie value using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript)