# cookie not save in IE

Tags: javascript, cookies

Cookie not save in IE but working fine in other browsers. I am using document.cookie .

**Example :**

```
function setCookie(name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quick question....is it 3rd party cookie? do you have _ in your server name?

Comment: No it is simple javascript function `document.cookie` @Kalish

Comment: There's no point in reinventing the wheel https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "best" way to get and set a single cookie value using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript)

Comment: I tried this befor but not workin @Mike

Comment: IE version.....???????

Comment: I don't know but how to replace this with jquery cookie plugin? @zamber

Comment: IE 8 and 9 ....... @Mike

Comment: Can you improve my given code? @Mike

Comment: @userknowmore, 1. Use jQuery if you're not using it yet. 2. add the plugin after jQuery. 3. Read docs and/or google before asking more questions.

Comment: @userknowmore are you running your script  from local system or remote server?

Comment: what yes...? **local system or remote server**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming, you are running your script from local machine and none the web page is opened its like `about:blank` opened. Recently, I faced a similar issue. My script couldn't store a cookie in IE in this case, although it worked well on all other major browsers. After some googling it turned out that IE ignores cookies from `about:blank`. After I uploaded the page to remote server code magically started to work.

I have opened [Google](https://www.google.co.in) and run your code it is working fine in IE9.

And I am hoping you have made required setting in browser(IE) settings. Like below

1. Open Internet Explorer 9
2. Click on the Tools icon on the very right at the top and then on
   Internet Options.
3. At the top switch to the tab Privacy and click on the Advanced
   button.
4. Allow First-Party Cookies and Third-Party Cookies and enable Session
   Cookies (As per your requirement).